# Consulta Excluyendo registros duplicados en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta en SQL server:

```
SELECT  [nIdLogTG]
      ,[nUsuario]
      ,[nConsDetalle]
      ,[nConsDoOrigen]
      ,(case when a.cCodigoComplementarioDo IS NULL THEN b.cCodigoComplementarioDo
      ELSE a.cCodigoComplementarioDo END) AS CodigoComplementarioDo,
      (case when c.CNombreCompleto IS NULL THEN d.CNombreCompleto
      ELSE c.CNombreCompleto END) AS NombreCompletoCliente
      ,[nConsDoDestino]
      ,(case when e.cCodigoComplementarioDo IS NULL THEN f.cCodigoComplementarioDo
      ELSE e.cCodigoComplementarioDo END) AS CodigoComplementarioDoDestino
      ,[dFechaLog]
      ,[NroCausacion]
      ,[NombreGasto]
      ,[Valor]
  FROM tbLog_TrasladodeGastos
   left join tbhencabezadodo a on tbLog_TrasladodeGastos.nConsDoOrigen = a.NConsDo
   left join tbEncabezadoDo b on tbLog_TrasladodeGastos.nConsDoOrigen = b.NConsDo
   left join tbCliente c on a.CCliente = c.CNit
   left join tbCliente d on b.CCliente = d.CNit
   left join tbhencabezadodo e on tbLog_TrasladodeGastos.nConsDodestino = e.NConsDo
   left join tbEncabezadoDo f on tbLog_TrasladodeGastos.nConsDodestino = f.NConsDo
   where dFechaLog > '2018-01-01'
```

La cual me trae el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito que no me muestre códigos `complementarios DO` repetidos, o `NconsDOrigen` con valores repetidos

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Sólo necesitas agregarle "group by" a tu consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que se ve en la tabla de ejemplo los registros que tienen el código complementario DO repetido tienen repetidos todos los otros campos, de modo que podrías agregar al final un:

```
GROUP BY nConsDoOrigen, CodigoComplementarioDo, NombreCompletoCliente, nConsDoDestino, CodigoComplementarioDoDestino
```

Incluso podrías agregan al select un:

```
COUNT(CodigoComplementarioDo) AS numero_registros
```

Con eso verías el número de repeticiones asociado a cada CodigoComplementarioDo

Espero aportar